# Undefined variable $http request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, undefined, angular-http

I'm performing a GET - request on my back end to retrieve some JSON - data. I want to store a part of the data in a variable because I want to use it after the request. But everytime, the variable is undefined while I did the same thing in another controller. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

This is the code:

```
 var itemNumber;
 $http.get(URLtoServer + 'serialNumber/' + $stateParams.serialNumber + '/?format=json').success(function(dataSerialNumber){
      itemNumber = dataSerialNumber.id;
    }).error(function(){
      //code
    });

    console.log(itemNumber);
    item.number = itemNumber;
```

EDIT POST CALL:

```
var postPromise = $http.post(URLtoServer + 'problem/', item);

  postPromise.success(function (response) {
    angular.extend(item, response);
    showIssueReportedAlert($mdDialog); 

    $http.get('assets/settings/general.json').success(function(data){
      companyURL = data[0].url;

      $timeout(function(){
        //$window.location.href = companyURL;
      }, 3000);
    });         
  });

  postPromise.error(function(){
    showErrorAlert($mdDialog);

    $scope.renderSendbutton = true;
    $scope.showProgressCircular = false;
  });
```

Comment: You should pass `$http`as a paramaters in the controller

Comment: Isn't $http.get asynchronous? If so you may be triing to access it before it is assigned.

Comment: like: `['$http', function($http){...}]`

Comment: `$http` is async so JS doesnot wait for it to complete and execute the next line which is the `console.log`, hence you get `itemnumber` as undefined. Whatever code depends on itemnumber, keep it inside `.success`.

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina yeah like that...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @Robert  I already thought so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your POST `$http` call inside a `function` and call it in the `.success` of the GET.

```
 var itemNumber;
 $http.get(URLtoServer + 'serialNumber/' + $stateParams.serialNumber + '/?format=json').success(function(dataSerialNumber){
      itemNumber = dataSerialNumber.id;

       console.log(itemNumber);
       item.number = itemNumber; 
       doPostCallNow(); //Calling the POST 
    }).error(function(){
      //code
    });

function doPostCallNow(){
    var postPromise = $http.post(URLtoServer + 'problem/', item); 
    //And rest of your code...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're doing an async `get` request, which returns immediately, and then assigning the itemNumber (which is undefined at the moment since the `get` request hasn't finished) to your `item.number`.

You need to do the assignment in the callback:

```
 var itemNumber;
 $http.get(URLtoServer + 'serialNumber/' + $stateParams.serialNumber + '/?format=json').success(function(dataSerialNumber){
      itemNumber = dataSerialNumber.id;

       console.log(itemNumber);
       item.number = itemNumber; 
    }).error(function(){
      //code
    });
```

Comment: after this get request, I do a POST - request to the backend and the "item.number" is still undefined

Comment: You'll need to share that code as well then so we could see what's wrong.

Comment: I have edited this question, you will find the POST-request code there